# Probability - Passing a Y/N test by knowing and guessing the answers (solve with code)

Tags: probability

So I am a bit lost regarding probability and would like to get a better grasp of how I should tackle problems.
The question that I am stuck with is the following:

Students are taking a Y/N test consisting of 20 questions where the probability of a student knowing the right answer follows $N \sim bin(20, 11/20)$, and the probability of guessing the right answers follows $Z \sim bin(20-N, 1/2)$. The total number of correct answers are defined as $Y = N + Z$. To pass a threshold ($T = \{0,1,...,20\}$) is set such that $Y ≥ T$. $N$ and $Z$ are independent.

(1) For each value of $T$, what is the probability that a student knows less than 10 questions, $N < 10$?

(2) What is the smallest value of $T$ such that if $Y ≥ T$ we are 90 % certain  that the students knows the answer to 10 or more questions, $N ≥ 10$?

I am thinking that I should use conditional probability for (1) but I don't know how to formulate or start with the problem, and I am clueless regarding (2)... Any tip or reference to similar problems are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be the event $N < 10$, let $B$ be the event $N + Z \geq T$. You want to find $P(A|B)$, which is $P(N<10 | N + Z \geq T)$.

Using the fact that $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$, we just need to find $P(B)$ and $P(A \cap B)$.

We have $P(B)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^T P(N=i)P(Z \geq T-i)$, which can be worked out via the distributions.

The probability that $N <10$ and $N+Z \geq T$ is simply $\sum\limits_{i=0}^9 P(N=i)P(Z \geq T-i)$, which again can be found via the distributions.

Then, you can calculate the final probability, dividing the latter by the former. You mention you can solve with code, so this should be enough for (1), but if you need further clarification let me know.

Part (2) asks the following: for what value of $T$ is $P(N \geq 10 | N + Z \geq T)$ at least 90%? This is the same as asking for the least $T$ such that
$$P(N<10 | N + Z \geq T) \leq 0.1$$

So you can use your answers from (1). Hope that makes sense, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I do have one question, if T = 2 then for P(N < 10 and N + Z ≥ T ) we get a negative value as soon as i > 2, which seems wrong

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure why that is. Do you think it's an error in my maths, or your code? Do the other answers look correct?

Comment: Probably my code but if T = 2 and i = 3 than wouldn't it mean that P(Z ≥ -1 ) would say "what is the probability that a student guessed correct on -1 or more question"? I guess that is what seems wrong to me

Comment: Right, in that case the probability is 1. Think about what you are actually asking - if the student knew 3 answers, what's the probability they get at least 2 right? Clearly it is 1, no matter how many they guess correctly.